# WPF/C#: Proper implementation for closing/hiding the form while new form is opening

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, show-hide

I was looking something similar with winforms like

```
// in Form 1
this.Hide();    
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show


// in Form 2
// if button pressed, Form 1 will be displayed, while Form 2 will be Hide.
```

I was trying my luck for FormEventHandler but doesn't know where to start.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For the purposes of this answer, `Form1` and `Form2` represent classes inheriting from `Windows.Window`)

I would recommend one of the following approaches

**Approach 1: Keeping `Form2` alive and able to show again**

In this case, you'll need to make an instance variable on `Form1`:

```
private Form2 form2;
```

In your code to "switch" to `Form2`, do this:

```
if(form2 == null)
{
    form2 = new Form2();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Window.VisibilityProperty, 
            typeof(Window)).AddValueChanged(form2, Form2_VisibilityChanged);
}

Hide();

form2.Show();
```

Then add this function to `Form1`:

```
private void Form2_VisiblityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(form2.Visility == Visibility.Hidden) Show();
}
```

Now all you need to do is call `Hide();` within `Form2` to have it switch back to `Form1`.

**Approach 2: Closing `Form2` and opening a new instance each time**

This is a bit easier, and more in line with what you have:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.Closed += Form2_Closed;

Hide();

form2.Show();
```

Similarly, add this function to `Form1`:

```
private void Form2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Show();
}
```

Now, instead of calling `Hide();` in `Form2`, call `Close();`

Comment: will this work the second time around? i mean, doing the implementation multiple times?

Comment: Error occured: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. > Form1.Show();

Comment: @eibhrum: I've revamped this answer in light of what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

The `Visiblity` property of a `Window` can be set to `Hidden` to hide it. So if you are in `Window1`:

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
Window2 win = new Window2();
win.Show();
```

To show the window again, simply change its `Visibility`.